# What does %k mean in Exec=?

Tags: .desktop, freedesktop

```
Exec=sh -c "some command' %k
```

No info in `man sh` and `man exec` on %k.
What does %k mean here?

Comment: `man exec` is about system call `exec` and its family, not about `.desktop` file.

Answer (score 6):

According  to the [Desktop Entry Specifications](https://standards.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/desktop-entry-spec-latest.html):

> %k    The location of the desktop file as either a URI (if for example gotten from the vfolder system) or a local filename or empty if no location is known.

What is *not* obvious from your example at first sight is that `sh -c '...'` (if that is POSIX `/bin/sh` and not symlinked to [csh](https://linux.die.net/man/1/csh)) sets positional arguments starting at `$0`, which means `$0` will be whatever is `%k`.

Comment: No system would be foolish enough to have a sh -> csh symlink. However some old ksh88-based `sh` implementations have been known to put the first argument after the inline script in `$1` instead of `$0`, which is why you sometimes see things like `sh -c 'code "$1"' arg arg` or `sh -c 'shift "$1"; code ${1+"$@"}' 2 1 args...`. Those shouldn't be needed anymore nowadays. Note that `$0` is not a positional argument per se.